# Proving a set is complete in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am trying to assess whether a set of formulas is complete in predicate logic. The language at hand only has a one-ary predicate S. 
I am proving whether a set is complete by showing the following:

1. Γ is consistent
2. for every φ ∈ L ,it holds that either ∆⊢nφ or ∆⊢n¬φ.

The set of formulas is {∃xSx, ∃x¬Sx}

How do I go about proving whether the set is complete? Intuitively I would say the set is not complete, since when we have a model with D = {1}, it would lead to a contradiction?

Comment: Does your predicate logic include equality as a logical symbol?

Comment: Your set of formulas is certainly consistent, as it has a model, for example a set of two elements of which only one satisfies $S$.  The fact that some other models, like the $D$ you suggest, don't satisfy your set is irrelevzant to consistency.

Comment: It does indeed include equality as a logical symbol. Thank you for the comment about consistency, that does indeed make sense. Proving that for any formula either it, or its negation is derivable, is more of a challenge. I think soundness can be used, but how to prove it is unclear to me.

Comment: In my previous comment, I described a model of your set with two elements. Try to design a model of your set with three elements.  Then, using equality, write a sentence saying that there are at most two distinct elements (i.e., of any three elements, some two are equal). That sentence is true in the one model and false in the other. Then use soundness to infer that neither that sentence nor its negation is deducible from your set.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. One more question: say the set Γ includes another element, ∀x∀y∀z(x=y v x=z v z=y), then am I correct to note that point 2 from the original definition will hold, and thus the set is complete?

Comment: Yes, adding that sentence would make the set complete.